# Cassandra configuration error in cassandra 3.10

Tags: cassandra

I am getting following error when I am trying to run cassandra for the first time. any  suggestion?

> CassandraDaemon.java:752 - Exception encountered during startup: Invalid yaml: file:/D:/apache-cassandra-3.10/conf/cassandra.yaml
>    Error: null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;  in 'reader', line 10, column 1:
>       cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
>       ^

Comment: Did you change anything in Cassandra.yaml file?. Add the contents of this file, so I could help you.

Comment: okay. I will update you once add content of this file.

Comment: hi @Shoban, it would be very clumsy to add whole yaml file content over here. and I haven't done any changes in it.

Comment: What is the jdk version you are using?

Comment: jdk version 1.8

Comment: During Cassandra startup, Cassandra configurations are loaded from this Cassandra.yaml file. So the issue which you have mentioned will come when you are starting Cassandra using wrong yaml file or trying to start Cassandra using any 3rd party code (java code)/application using wrong version of Cassandra.jar. Are you starting from Command line by running Cassandra.bat ?

Comment: yes, I am running cassandra.bat file in bin folder

Answer (score 0):

check the `cassandra.yaml` file. Even if it seems to have correct format, there must be a space after `:` for each property.

In my case I modified seeds like below:

```
seeds:"IP1,IP2"
```

which caused the same error.
Misleadingly the error indicates the `cluster_name`.
I put the space after colon

```
seeds: "IP1,IP2"
```

and started Cassandra service. The error disappeared and Cassandra was able to start successfully.